# Angular ui-router, scroll to next step on state change with different controller and template

Tags: angularjs, uiview, angular-ui-router, angularjs-controller, ngboilerplate

I'm using UI-router in my app and I'd like to so a simple "scrollTo" to an anchor when the URL/state changes. I want to load new controller and template when state changes.
I'm using ng-boilerplate.

> Index file

```
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" collapse="menuCollapsed" ng-click="collapse()">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right nav-link">
              <li ui-sref-active="active">
                <a href ui-sref="home">
                  <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
                  Home
                </a>
              </li>
              <li ui-sref-active="active">
                <a href ui-sref="service">
                  <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
                  Service
                </a>
              </li>
              <li ui-sref-active="active">
                <a href ui-sref="portfolio">
                  <i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>
                  Portfolio
                </a>
              </li>
              <li ui-sref-active="active">
                <a href ui-sref="team">
                  <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
                  Team
                </a>
              </li>
              <li ui-sref-active="active">
                <a href ui-sref="testimonial">
                  <i class="fa fa-comments"></i>
                  Testimonial
                </a>
              </li>
              <li ui-sref-active="active">
                <a href ui-sref="contact">
                  <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                  Contact
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div ui-view="main">
    </div>
```

> Home template and js

```
<div class="banner">
    <div class="intro-body">
        <h1>CREATIVE DIGITAL<br> SOLOUTIONS</h1>
        <p>Proin iaculis consequat sem cure.</p>
        <a href ui-sref="portfolio" class="btn btn-success">VIEW PORTFOLIO</a>
    </div>
</div>


angular.module( 'ngBoilerplate.home', [
  'ui.router',
  'plusOne'
])

/**
 * Each section or module of the site can also have its own routes. AngularJS
 * will handle ensuring they are all available at run-time, but splitting it
 * this way makes each module more "self-contained".
 */
.config(function config( $stateProvider ) {
  $stateProvider.state( 'home', {
    url: '/home',
    views: {
      "main": {
        controller: 'HomeCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'home/home.tpl.html'
      }
    },
    data:{ pageTitle: 'Home' }
  });
})

/**
 * And of course we define a controller for our route.
 */
.controller( 'HomeCtrl', function HomeController( $scope ) {
})

;
```

> Service Template & Js

```
<div class="container" id="service">
    <div class="service-intro">
        <h2>Why to choose company?</h2>
</div>
</div>

angular.module( 'service', [
    'ui.router'
])
.config(function config( $stateProvider ) {
    $stateProvider.state( 'service', {
        url: '/service',
        views: {
            "main": {
                controller: 'ServiceCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'service/service.tpl.html'
            }
        },
        data:{ pageTitle: 'service' }
    });
})
.controller( 'ServiceCtrl', function HomeController( $scope ) {
})

;
```

> APP JS

```
angular.module( 'ngBoilerplate', [
  'templates-app',
  'templates-common',
  'ngBoilerplate.home',
  'ngBoilerplate.about',
  'service',
  'portfolio',
  'team',
  'testimonial',
  'contact-us',
  'ui.router',
  'ngAnimate'
])

.config( function myAppConfig ( $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider ) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise( '/home' );
})

.run( function run () {
})

.controller( 'AppCtrl', function AppCtrl ( $scope, $location,$rootScope ) {
      $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function () {
        $scope.slide = $scope.slide || 'slide-left';
      });
      $scope.collapse = function() {
        $scope.menuCollapsed = true;
      };
  $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
    if ( angular.isDefined( toState.data.pageTitle ) ) {
      $scope.pageTitle = toState.data.pageTitle + ' | Teknuk' ;
    }
  });
})

;
```

So, when you enter the page the URL would be domain.com/home

When you click the first button I'd like my controller code to change the URL to domain.com/#/service and scroll down to the "service" div and controller + template updated.

Ideally, when the user hits the back button it would revert to the first URL and scroll back up to home.

Anybody know how to do this?

Comment: So basically you want normal normal change of states but trigger a scrollTo con each, to a particular html elementos right? Why don't you just make use of states in `.config()` function and call a `.scrollTo()` based on each states custom property `data: {}` on each state's change? Provide me a live example and I'll try it for you

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont use native scrolling ? https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#autoscroll